# Passing a list from Controller.php to .js file in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a list of numbers in my pageController.php

```
$half2018 = [235, 1234, 134, 564, 364, 362];
return view('page', 'half2018'=>$half2018);
```

I call that variable in my page.blade.php

```
<canvas id="chart_1" class="chart-canvas" data-info="{{ $half2018 }}"></canvas>
```

Then at the end of page.blade.php I have

```
<script src="./assets/js/chart.js"></script>
```

In my chart.js file I call

```
let app = document.getElementById('claims_chart_12');
let info = JSON.parse(app.dataset.id);
console.log(info);
```

For some reason, JSON library is not loaded. Is it a right way to pass the data to .js file?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in your controller should be

```php
$half2018 = [235, 1234, 134, 564, 364, 362];

return view('page', ['half2018' => $half2018]);
```

or

```php
return view('page', compact('half2018'));
```

---

In your blade file, you can set the variable in a `data-*` attribute **after** it's converted to valid JSON. Use single quotes for it.

```xml
<canvas id="chart_1" class="chart-canvas" data-info='{{ json_encode($half2018) }}'></canvas>
```

I think this is equivalent to

```xml
<canvas id="chart_1" class="chart-canvas" data-info='@json($half2018)'></canvas>
```

---

Then, in your js, you can parse this JSON.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('chart_1');
let info = JSON.parse(canvas.dataset.id);
console.log(info);
```

Comment: let info = JSON.parse(app.dataset.info)
was what I was looking for. It is working now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

@IGP pointed out my syntax in Controller.php. After I changed the line in chart.js file to

```
let info = JSON.parse(canvas.dataset.info);
console.log(info)
```

then I get

```
[235, 1234, 134, 564, 364, 362]
```

in my .js file.